# Is this set linearly independent or dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra

The set ${{(e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x})}}$ is linearly independent but is the set ${{(1,e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x})}}$ linearly independent too? The determinant of the matrix formed by the set ${{(e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x})}}$ is non zero which implies its linearly independent. But I don't know how to approach this set ${{(1,e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x})}}$, is it linearly independent or dependent? I think its linearly independent but I guess I'm just thrown off by that 1 and am not sure. Can someone confirm it for me?

Comment: Did you try do compute the Wronskian of $(1,e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x})$? It is quite simple because you have many zeros in the first column!

Comment: Determinant of which matrix exactly?

Comment: **What** do you mean by "the matrix formed by $(e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x})$"???????????

Comment: I wasn't clear, I meant the Wronskian matrix of the set ${{(e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x})}}$ @DavidC.Ullrich

Comment: So you should fix the question! Note what happens when you click on the word "edit" just below your post...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll sketch a proof for the linear independence of the vectors $(1,e^x,e^{2x})$: Assume that there exist $a,b,c \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\},$ such that $a+be^x+ce^{2x}=0$. Then we can evaluate at certain values and get
\begin{align}
x=0 &\implies a+b+c=0\\
x=1 &\implies a+be+ce^2=0\\
x=2 &\implies a+be^2+ce^4=0 \tag {$*$}
\end{align}
Then, by manipulating these expressions, you'll get that $b=-c(1+e)$ and that $a=ce$. Plugging this into equation $(*)$, you get
$$
0=ce-c(1+e)e^2+ce^4 = c(\underbrace{e-(1+e)e^2+e^4}_{\neq0}),
$$
hence $c=0$ and thus $a=b=0$ as well. I leave it up to you to fill in the details and prove the linear independence of $(1,e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x})$.

Comment: Solving the equations was a pain but I was able to prove ${{(1,e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x})}}$ is linearly independent, thanks for this.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

The linear independency can be proved without much calculation. Here are two possible approaches:

**Approach #1:** The Wronskian determinant of $(1,e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x})$ is
$$
 W(1,e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x}) = \begin{vmatrix}
 1 & e^x & e^{2x} & e^{3x} \\
 0 & e^x & 2e^{2x} & 3e^{3x} \\
 0 & e^x & 2^2e^{2x} & 3^2e^{3x} \\
 0 & e^x & 2^3e^{2x} & 3^3e^{3x} 
\end{vmatrix} = e^{6x }\begin{vmatrix}
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
 0 & 1^2 & 2^2 & 3^2 \\
 0 & 1^2 & 2^3 & 3^3 
\end{vmatrix} \, .
$$
The matrix on the right is a [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) and its determinant is known:
$$
W(1,e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x}) = e^{6x } \prod_{0 \le i < j \le 3} (j-i) \ne 0 \, .
$$
It follows that the functions $(1,e^x,e^{2x},e^{3x})$ are linearly independent.

The same method works for the functions
$$ \tag{$*$}
 (e^{a_1 x}, e^{a_2 x},\ldots , e^{a_n x})
$$
where the numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$ are pairwise distinct.

**Approach #2:** Assume that
$$
 a + be^x + ce^{2x} + d e^{3x} = 0
$$
for all $x \in \Bbb R$.For $x \to -\infty$ all terms except the first one converge to zero, and it follows that $a = 0$. But then we can divide the remaining sum by $e^x$ and conclude that
$$
 b + ce^{x} + d e^{2x} = 0
$$
for all $x \in \Bbb R$. With the same argument as before it follows that $b=0$. Now rinse and repeat ...

This approach works also for the general case $(*)$ for real pairwise distinct numbers $a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n$.